# the_tags outputs before echo

Tags: tags

The following very simple snippet of code is not working right: the tags are being displayed in the page, but outside of the span with class "tags".

```
echo '<span class="tags">' . the_tags('See also: ', ' &middot; ') . '</span>';
```

Here's the output:

```
See also: 
<a href="#" rel="tag">animals</a> · 
<a href="#" rel="tag">communities</a> · 
<a href="#" rel="tag">cultural differences</a> · 
<a href="#" rel="tag">projects</a>
<span class="tags"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`the_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) doesn't return the links but immediately echoes them. As that happens before the `echo` they appear before the span.

What you want is this:

```
echo '<span class="tags">';
the_tags('See also: ', ' &middot; ');
echo '</span>';
```

or even simpler

```
the_tags( '<span class="tags"> See also: ',' &middot; ', '</span>' );
```

As a general rule of thumb you can remember that function that start with `the_` directly echo things, while functions starting with `get_` return stuff.

So here you could also be using this:

```
echo '<span class="tags">' . get_the_tag_list('See also: ', ' &middot; ') . '</span>';
```

Comment: Fantastic, @kraftner! Thank you for the detailed answer.